# Can I trick instanceof with JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdom

I have a react class I want to test, and the class has this if check at the start:

```js
if (!(root instanceof window.HTMLElement)) {
   throw new Error('No HTML element was supplied. );
}
```

I've tried to pass in a fake element with `jsdom` but it didn't 'fool' the instanceof check.

```js
const doc = (new JSDOM()).window.document;
const root = doc.createElement("div");
const pizza = new Builder(root);
expect(pizza).toBeDefined();
```

I've looked at what gets passed in

```
if (!(root instanceof window.HTMLElement)) {
  console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(root));
  console.log(typeof window.HTMLElement)
  console.log(typeof root)
  throw new Error('No HTML element was supplied. );
}
```

And it doesn't look anything like window.HTMLElement:

```
    console.log src/main.jsx:20
      [object HTMLDivElement]
    console.log src/main.jsx:21
      function
    console.log src/main.jsx:22
      object
```

How can I mock the `window.HTMLElement` so I can test this class?

Comment: What is it your testing tool.? Enzyme, RTL+Jest...?

Comment: `HTMLDivElement` inherits from `HTMLElement`, so anything that's `instanceof HTMLDivElement` should also be `instanceof HTMLElement`. Not quite clear on what your issue is here?

Comment: @Yevgen Enzyme and Jest, but neither of those are causing an issue in the code supplied.

Comment: I asked because I cannot get it ***why*** you're doing the above (since for basic testing whether component is rendered there's a shorter path) and what's the purpose of JSDOM here?

Comment: @Yevgen what's the shorter path?

Comment: @LionelRowe it doesn't work, so I suspect it's not really a `HTMLDivElement`? I've updated the question to be clearer

Comment: @LionelRowe, when I check `console.log(root.prototype instanceof window.HTMLElement)` I get `false`. What does that mean?

Comment: `prototype` is not the same as `__proto__` - `prototype` on an instance will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock properties of `window` by assigning them as properties of `global`. The instance of `JSDOM` will need to be the same between assigning the global property and using it to create elements, otherwise the instance of `HTMLElement` will also differ. To get around this limitation, we reference it as the single variable `jsDomInstance` set up in `beforeEach`, rather than instantiating multiple copies.

```js
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')

const { instanceofCheck } = require('./instanceofCheck')
// const instanceofCheck = x => x instanceof window.HTMLElement

describe('JSDOM tests', () => {
    let jsDomInstance

    beforeEach(() => {
        jsDomInstance = new JSDOM()
        global.HTMLElement = jsDomInstance.window.HTMLElement
    })

    it('passes instanceof check', () => {
        expect(
            instanceofCheck(
                jsDomInstance.window.document.createElement('div')
            )
        ).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@lionel_rowe/jsdom-mock)